# following tutorial but not giving me the options it should

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

i'm following the http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-3 tutorial word for word but there is no option for me to enable or disable SkyWalker.Webshop.

I have done as it asks, created the 'Skywalker.Webshop' folder inside the 'modules' folder. delete the class1.cs file and add the Module.text file.

However when I load the application there is no option in the modules/features page that allows me to enable or disable webshop (why does it not appear)

anyone have any idea as to why?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you added the text inside Module.txt? Have you built your project/solution?

Answer (score 0):

according to what mentioned in the tutorial :

**Orchard requires that your module exists physically in the Modules directory.**

make sure you have supplied right directory when creating class library, cause visual studio uses most recent directory supplied for project of type `class library` when you attempt to add new class library to orchard solution.

hope this help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it in another way:

Using command line tool (Orchard.exe under bin folder)

type the following

```
feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration
```

Then,

```
codegen module Pluralsight.Movies /IncludInSolution:true
```

Hints:
use "help commends", "help codegen module"

to help you understand the command line.